# Initialized foreign key in dynamic table

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, foreign-keys

.I start to write diet planner project and this is my database tables .I use external database and define tables foreign key there and copy it in asset folder and then connect it to my project.
standardUnit,Foods and standardFoodUnit are 3 tables which have static data and I filled them before,but EatenFood table is dynamically filled after Calculations.
 I use model class and try to write databaseAdapter with [androidhive database tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XNIR.png) instruction.but because I started android recently I don't have any vision about it.
try to read book or online tutorial but they mixing up me more. now this is my question,I want to know for EatenFood table foreign key how can I put food-id value?I defined `food_id       INTEGER REFERENCES Foods ( _id )` in database before but in databaseAdapter class for insert or update or get function I don't know how can behave with this foreign key.

[image]

this is model class for EatenFood table

```
public class EatenFood {

int eatenfoodid;
boolean breakfast;
boolean lunch;
boolean snack;
boolean appetizers;
boolean dinner;
Data day;
String equivalent;
boolean dairy;
boolean vegetables;
boolean fruit;
boolean meat_bean_egg;
boolean bread_cereals;
boolean fat;
boolean suger;
double unitsum;
int food_id;

public boolean isAppetizers() {
    return appetizers;
}
public void setAppetizers(boolean appetizers) {
    this.appetizers = appetizers;
}
public Data getDay() {
    return day;
}
public void setDay(Data day) {
    this.day = day;
}
public double getUnitsum() {
    return unitsum;
}
public void setUnitsum(double unitsum) {
    this.unitsum = unitsum;
}
public int getFood_id() {
    return food_id;
}
public void setFood_id(int food_id) {
    this.food_id = food_id;
}
//all remaining getter and setter .........}
```

model class for food table

```
public class Foods {
int foodid;
String foodname;
boolean breakfast;
boolean lunch;
boolean snack;
boolean appetizers;
boolean dinner;
boolean mainfood;
boolean secondary;


public boolean isAppetizers() {
    return appetizers;
}
public void setAppetizers(boolean appetizers) {
    this.appetizers = appetizers;
}
public int getFoodid() {
    return foodid;
}
public void setFoodid(int foodid) {
    this.foodid = foodid;
}
//all remaining getter and setter .........}
```

DatabaseAdapter Functions

```
public class DatabaseAdapter {

private final String TAG = "DatabaseAdapter";
private DatabaseOpenHelper openHelper;
public Long insertEatenFood(EatenFood eatenfood) {
    SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = null;
    Long id = -1L;
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_BREAKFAST, eatenfood.isBreakfast());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_LUNCH, eatenfood.isLunch());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_SNACK, eatenfood.isSnack());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_APPETIZERS, eatenfood.isAppetizers());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_DINNER, eatenfood.isDinner());
        // values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_DATA, eatenfood.getDay().getClass());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_EQUIVALENT, eatenfood.getEquivalent());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_DAIRY, eatenfood.isDairy());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_VEGETABLES, eatenfood.isVegetables());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_FRUIT, eatenfood.isFruit());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_MEAT_BEAN_EGG,
                eatenfood.isMeat_bean_egg());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_BREAD_CEREALS,
                eatenfood.isBread_cereals());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_FAT, eatenfood.isFat());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_SUGER, eatenfood.isSuger());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_UNITSUM, eatenfood.getUnitsum());

        myDataBase = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        id = myDataBase.insert(TABLE_EATENFOOD, null, values);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (myDataBase != null && myDataBase.isOpen())
            myDataBase.close();
    }
    return id;
}

// update EateanFood table =====================================================
public int updateEatenFood(EatenFood eatenfood) {
    SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = null;
    int count = -1;
    try {
        myDataBase = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_BREAKFAST, eatenfood.isBreakfast());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_LUNCH, eatenfood.isLunch());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_SNACK, eatenfood.isSnack());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_APPETIZERS, eatenfood.isAppetizers());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_DINNER, eatenfood.isDinner());
        // values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_DATA, eatenfood.getDay().getClass());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_EQUIVALENT, eatenfood.getEquivalent());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_DAIRY, eatenfood.isDairy());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_VEGETABLES, eatenfood.isVegetables());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_FRUIT, eatenfood.isFruit());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_MEAT_BEAN_EGG,
                eatenfood.isMeat_bean_egg());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_BREAD_CEREALS,
                eatenfood.isBread_cereals());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_FAT, eatenfood.isFat());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_SUGER, eatenfood.isSuger());
        values.put(TABLE_EATENFOOD_UNITSUM, eatenfood.getUnitsum());

        count = myDataBase
                .update(TABLE_EATENFOOD, values, TABLE_EATENFOOD_ID + "=?",
                        new String[] { String.valueOf(eatenfood
                                .getEatenfoodid()) });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        myDataBase.close();
    }
    return count;
}

//  Getting All EatenFood ================================================

public ArrayList<EatenFood> getEatenfoods() {

    ArrayList<EatenFood> result = null;
    SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        myDataBase = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        cursor = myDataBase.query(TABLE_EATENFOOD, new String[] { "*" }, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            result = new ArrayList<EatenFood>();
            do {
                result.add(extractEatenFood(cursor));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } 
    finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        myDataBase.close();
    }
    return result;      
}

// extractEatenFood=============================================================
private EatenFood extractEatenFood(Cursor cursor){
    EatenFood eatenfood = new EatenFood();
    eatenfood.setEatenfoodid(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_EATENFOOD_ID)));
    eatenfood.setBreakfast(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_EATENFOOD_BREAKFAST)) != 0);
    eatenfood.setLunch(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_EATENFOOD_LUNCH))!=0);
    eatenfood.setSnack(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_EATENFOOD_SNACK))!=0);
    eatenfood.setAppetizers(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_EATENFOOD_APPETIZERS))!=0);
    eatenfood.setDinner(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_EATENFOOD_DINNER))!=0);
    //      ???????????????????????? baraye day k sabt beshe
    eatenfood.setEquivalent(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_EATENFOOD_EQUIVALENT)));
    eatenfood.setDairy(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_EATENFOOD_DAIRY))!=0);
    eatenfood.setVegetables(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_EATENFOOD_VEGETABLES))!=0);
    eatenfood.setFruit(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_EATENFOOD_FRUIT))!=0);
    eatenfood.setBread_cereals(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_EATENFOOD_BREAD_CEREALS))!=0);
    eatenfood.setFat(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_EATENFOOD_FAT))!=0);
    eatenfood.setSuger(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_EATENFOOD_SUGER))!=0);
    eatenfood.setFood_id(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_EATENFOOD_F_FOODID)));


    return eatenfood ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to add a food into you're `eatenfood` table. You have to call `getFoodid` function on you're specific food object and get the `food_id` and after that insert into database with `insertEatenFood` function in you're `DatabaseAdapter` class.
It's better you mention you're whole example of you're question that's makes it more easy to help you.
Maybe you got a problem about how can you find the food_id's that you want to insert into you're `eatenfood` table. It's better to write you're algorithms after that you find out which `food_id`'s gonna be needed for you're different users.